# Angular httpClient - RXJS usage

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am wondering whether the following usage is efficient way to fetch data from an external API.

```js
getProducts(): Promise<Array<Product>> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.httpClient.get<[Product]>(this.apiURL, { responseType: 'json' })
      .pipe(
        retry(3),
        first(),
        tap(
          data => resolve(data),
          error => reject(error)
        )
      ).subscribe();
  });
}
```

Especially I am concerned about the `subscribe()` part, I couldn't get the `tap()` executed without `subscribe`.

I am new to Angular-RxJs-TypeScript, please excuse me.

Comment: nope.if you use rxjs it's much better.angular uses rxjs to improve async operators.so you can use rxjs without promise in this function.if you really need promise then you can call `.topromise()` method on observable.

of cause tap() wont execute until subscribe is called.unlike promises observable  doesn't execute without subscribe

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.

Angular is built on RxJS, which is a library for handling asynchronous streams. RxJS has a concept of an "Observable", which replaces anything you'd use a promise for. If you have to work with a Promise for any reason (maybe it's provided in a 3rd party library), then you'd use the `from` operator in RxJS to just convert it to an Observable.

If you really need to use Promises, then Angular isn't the right framework. In fact, Angular's change detection system is built using another library called Zone.js that doesn't even support async/await.

A word of caution, RxJS has a steep learning curve, so be prepared to dive into it if you keep moving forward with Angular.